# setProgressbar not updating inside getView form a thread running on activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with each item having a ProgressBar on top. My own created thread running and downloading the data in background and have to show download progress in getView part for each item, but i'm not able to update the setProgressbar in getView method of adapter.

But when user scrolls up and down(away from particular view) then its update the progress and freezes and not increasing based on download percentage.

**My thread code**

```js
downloading = Ion.with(LoadTumblrActivity.this)
  .load(item.getGifUrl())
  // can also use a custom callback
  // can also use a custom callback

.progress(new ProgressCallback() {

    @
    Override
    public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {

      float progressVal = ((float) downloaded / (float) total);

      item.setProgress((int)(100 * progressVal));

    }
  })
  .write(
    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/sdcard" + fileName))
  .setCallback(new FutureCallback < File > () {

    @
    SuppressLint("SdCardPath")@ Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, File file) {
      {

        if (e != null) {
          Toast.makeText(LoadTumblrActivity.this, "Error downloading file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          System.out.println(e);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

**My BaseAdapter**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        // reuse views
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);
            // configure view holder
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

          holder.progressBar.setProgress(item.getProgress());

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that you call

```
holder.progressBar.setProgress(item.getProgress());
```

inside your `getView` and `getView` is only called for the items visible on the Screen. That's why your `ProgressBar` only updates when you scroll for the Items which Comes to Screen due to scrolling! You Need to call this line outside of the `getView` for example in an `AsyncTask` when you call `publishProgress();` in `onProgressUpdate` to give user a real experience of how Long it takes till the item appears/finished downloading.

Another Approach would be to set the progressBar to `intermediate= "false"` and only Show a spinning progressbar! ;)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Mike,I will try. will AsyncTask update the progress of other views' progressBar which are not in view of screen.

Comment: @zeeshanansari I think Yes but you will Need to hold a reference to that specific progressBar. Simply pass the reference to that progressBar to the AsyncTask you can make a nested AsyncTask in you BaseAdapter class! `onProgressUpdate` is developed for updating a progressBar and other stuffs during `doInBackGround` runs! This isn't untricky what you want to try. Because the `BaseAdapter` reuses old views. Even the progressBar if you declare it in your `getView`

Comment: How can i pass that reference to AsyncTask?

Comment: @zeeshanansari  `viewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.progress);` In that caseviewHolder.progressBar is your reference. But i would not put the reference into the holder because that way you would reuse existing progressBars! And i'm not sure which behaviour you get when reusing a progressBar which should be unique for every item! As i said this is tricky what you want to do! You could pass that reference to the constructor of your asynctask-class like you do it with every other class and then use this reference inside your asynctask :)

Comment: @zeeshanansari something like `MyAsyncTaskClass letsDoIt = new MyAsyncTaskClass(your reference of the progressbar)`.... `letsDoIt.execute();` And your construtor of the AsyncTask would look like this: `public MyAsyncTaskClass(ProgressBar myProgressBarReference)`; hope it helps ;)

Comment: @zeeshanansari as i said its tricky and that's a completely new Point how to implement this. But i provided you the Information of your origin Problem why this occurs and what to do to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Use runOnuiThread to update progress bar:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressDialog.setMessage(ii+" Apps Loaded...");
                ii++;
            }
        });
```

Source code from [Helper+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=helper.plus)

Comment: I have used this but app crashes when i have multiple downloads in view. Any other suggestion other than using runOnUiThread?

Comment: I think this is the good way to update UI and even i am using it in app helper+. Try it again and check where you are getting problem when using it.

Comment: As i said when user scrolls up and down every time thread created using runOnUiThread lead to app crash. Do you any suggestion to stop creating new thread each time on scroll?

Comment: I don't know about your project but if you have multiple download options you can use notification, or use simple progressbar and set  like pb.setProgress(level); and one more thing use File.seperators instead of "/" ..i am using simple progress bar in cleaner and working fine when memory cleans.

Comment: My app is very simple. Just download gif files(more than one) from server in background and posting the progress what is happening while downloading and once gifs are completely downloaded show it to user in listView from SD card.